# Website loads GPU to 50% - is there a way to somehow restrict it?

Tags: browser, gpu, website

I'm not sure if I can leave a link here, but this is the website: https://dodem.ru/tasks/232/
I'm kinda forced to use it, since its the only place on the internet that provide solved problems from a specific russian calculus textbook. But the problem is, this website for some reason loads my GPU to 50%. And problem remains whether I use Chrome or Edge. I don't know if the owners are mining bitcoins or its just some coding bugs stacked together, but I'd really like to either solve this problem browser-wise, or at least ban this particular website from doing that. Is there a way?

Comment: Disable JavaScript on that page?

Comment: Nope, problem remains even if disabled, but you can no longer use the website...

Comment: I didn't notice anything out of the ordinary with that website.